# How it possible to grant access in Auroura app?

Tags: permissions, 22.04

When I wanted to run the Auroura app (I downloaded and installed it from [this](https://github.com/legacyO7/Aurora)) to manage the keyboard backlight in Ubuntu 22.04, unfortunately, after many clicks on "Grant Access" nothing happened as in the below image.
[image]

Anyone could help me to grant access to the mentioned app?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1498597/edit) your question and add information about where you got this application (provide link) and how it is installed.

Comment: why ask us? close to nobody here will be using it. It is a github page. see the "issues" tab and file a bug report

Comment: Please be more specific with your information. Did you install the appimage or the deb-package?

Comment: @mook765 I install .deb file.

Comment: Please always edit your question to add relevant information, do not use comments. All relevant information should be in the question body. I cannot reproduce your problem so far, but I stopped when I was asked to install addititional moduls from github. You should probably decribe precisely all steps you took when opening the application until you get stuck. Maybe you should really report a bug, but also then, precise information is needed to get help.